# How can I get meta data of a visualforce page which is used in a Page Layout of a particular object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, metadata-api, page-layout, metadata

I have a question i.e. how can I possibly extract meta data of a Visualforce page inside a Page Layout of an object.

For fetching the page layout I use following API request :

```
https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/describe/layouts
```

but using this if there is a visualforce page inside a particular page layout, it only shows that a visualforce page has been added, but it doesn't gives what input fields has been there in that particular VF page.

How can I get meta data of a VF page.

Here is where I am insering my VF page : 
[image: VF page inside Page layout]

TIA

Comment: What's the purpose for what you're trying to do? This may be an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hey, @sfdcfox, here I am trying to obtain the elements used in the visulforce page in a particular page layout and depending on the contents of the page I need to perform some actions.

Comment: Question has been edited to give better clarity of my problem

Comment: Again, *why* do you want this? What's the *reason* behind it? What are you attempting to accomplish? Did you read the previous link?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the Visualforce page name(s), retrieve the Visualforce page contents via the Metadata API and decode the content from base64 to binary.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_pages.htm

Parse the text content of the page to identify fields (for example, find all apex:inputField elements) and extract their names.

Because the field names occur in a whole plethora of different Visualforce components and HTML elements, this is not an extensible solution, but it could accomplish the task for a specific page.